# Function has different outputs with the same input, when I call another function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two Functions:

`createBlock(block)` which takes an array from `BLOCKS_MATRIX` and should generate the same array in the layout of `DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID`. This works correctly, when I don't call the function `createListOfBlocksGrid()`.

`createListOfBlocksGrid()` which loops thru `BLOCKS_MATRIX`, takes the value of the object and calls `createBlock(block)`. Somehow every array created with `createBlock()` returns the array:

```
[
  [true, true, true, true], 
  [true, true, true, true], 
  [true, true, true, false]
]
```

The funny thing is when I call `createBlock(block)` alone with a block and afterwards the `createListOfBlockGrid()` the single call `createBlock(block)` produces the same wrong output. However when I dont call `createListOfBlockGrid()` it produces the correct output.

```js
const BLOCKS_MATRIX =  {1: [[true]], 2: [[true,true]], 3: [[true,true],[false,true]], 4: [[true,true,true]], 5: [[true,true,true, true]], 6: [[false, false, true],[true,true,true]], 7: [[true, true, false], [false, true, true]], 8: [[true, true], [true, true]], 9: [[false, true, false], [true, true, true]], 10: [[false, true, true], [true, true, false], [false, true, false]], 11: [[true, true, true, true, true]], 12: [[true, true, true, true], [false, false, false, true]], 13: [[true, true, true, false], [false, false, true, true]], 14: [[true, true, true], [false, true, true]], 15: [[true, true, true], [false, true, false], [false, true, false]], 16: [[true, true, true], [true, false, true]], 17: [[true, true, true], [false, false, true], [false, false, true]], 18: [[false, false, true], [false, true, true], [true, true, false]], 19: [[false, true, false], [true, true, true], [false, true, false]], 20: [[true, true, true, true], [false, false, true, false]], 21: [[true, true, false], [false, true, false], [false, true, true]]}
const DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID = [[false, false, false, false], [false, false, false, false], [false, false, false, false]]

function createBlock(block) {
  let newBlock = DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID

  for (let i = 0; i < DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID.length; i++) {
    if (block.length <= i)
      break;

    for (let j = 0; j < DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID[i].length; j++) {
      if (block.length[i] <= j) 
        break;

      if (block[i][j] == true) {
        newBlock[i][j] = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return newBlock
}

console.log("Test")
console.log(createBlock([
  [true, true],
  [false, true]
]))

function createListOfBlocksGrid() {
  let BlocksGrid = []
  let block;

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(BLOCKS_MATRIX)) {
    block = createBlock(value)
    BlocksGrid.push(value)
  }

  return BlocksGrid
}

console.log(createListOfBlocksGrid())
```

I've tried to create an array of the values from the object and loop thru this in `createListOfBlocksGrid()` but it produces the same wrong output.

Comment: You shouldn't reuse your default definition, that's being used over and over and will keep the issue in there. You should clone it somehow, easiest way is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(DEFAULT))` or something. (to summise: `let newBlock` isn't actually a new block, its recycling the default block)

Comment: There's that, or [`StructuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Comment: Oooh @DavidThomas Neat, heard of it vaguely but hadn't had a need for it. It's available now, woopwoop. So yeah, use that.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript "const" keyword does not prevent modifications to the array elements themselves. Your DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID value was also getting updated in every run. I moved it inside create block function and it is working fine

```
function createBlock (block) {
 const DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID = [[false, false, false, false], [false, 
  false,false, false], [false, false, false, false]]
  let newBlock = DEFAULT_BLOCK_GRID
   /* ... */
}
```